# How to change the size of only one string in JTextArea?

Tags: java, string, swing, size, jtextarea

how can i change the size of a string?
for example:
my algorithm reads text, and outputs that in textArea.
if my algorithm finds this line "Ende erstes Algorithmus " in the text (the text is very long),
changes the size of this string or makes the string fat.

Comment: change the size of the string>???? u mean make a word hello to he????

Comment: Do you mean changes the **font size**? because changing the size of the string doesn't make sense.

Comment: i mean changes the font size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html):

> ...text area can display text in any font, all of the text is in the same font.

[JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) and [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) are far more suitable for styled text display and even support some HTML formatting.

Here is a basic idea you can play with:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setText("Plain text with <strong>bold</strong> part.");
        frame.add(textPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Check out [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are interested in the font size as @khelwood mentioned you cannot change the font of just a piece of `String` on `JTextArea`. Changes are applied to the whole text.

You can use different text component to achieve this though. See for instance [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)